# selecting the text string

Tags: sed, awk

ABCDchinchwad18-Mar-2010-11.sql.zip

ABCDsolapur18-Mar-2010-10.sql.zip

How do I find the string between "ABCD" and the date "18-Mar-2010"

Expected resuts:

chinchwad

solapur

Comment: The string can have a number in it. for e.g. ABCDpune218-Mar-2010-10.sql.zip # and I want to return pune2 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/ABCD\(.*\)[0-9]\{2\}-[[:alpha:]].*.sql.zip/\1/'
```

Output:

```
chinchwad

solapur

pune2
```

To remove the path added by `find` (which is more flexible, portable and maintainable than [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)):

```
sed 's|.*/ABCD\(.*\)[0-9]\{2\}-[[:alpha:]].*.sql.zip|\1|'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in ABCD*zip
do
  file="${file/#ABCD/}"
  echo ${file%%[0-9][0-9]-*-*}
done
```

or using sed

```
ls ABCD*zip | sed 's/^ABCD//;s/[0-9][0-9]-.*-.*//'
```

or using awk

```
ls ABCD*zip | awk -F"[0-9][0-9]-|ABCD" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: @ghostdog74, the OP has a new requirement in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should head to regexps

```
"ABCDchinchwad18-Mar-2010-11.sql.zip".match(/ABCD(\w+)[0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}/)[1]; //chinchwad
"ABCDsolapur18-Mar-2010-10.sql.zip".match(/ABCD(\w+)[0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}/)[1]; // solapur
```

Answer (score 0):

The filename contains the following input content

> ABCDchinchwad18-Mar-2010-11.sql.zip
>
> ABCDsolapur18-Mar-2010-10.sql.zip

```
sed -r 's/([A-Z]+)([a-z]+)(.*)/\2/' filename
```

The output is

> chinchwad
>
> solapur

Comment: # find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.zip" | sed -r 's/([A-Z]+)([a-z]+)(.*)/\2/' 

## ./chinchwad and ./solapur # how do remove the path?

Comment: @shantanuo, if you are using maxdepth 1, you might as well just do a listing using `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Perl will do well here:

```
ls *.zip | perl -pe 's/ABCD (\w+) \d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} .*/$1/x'
```

If you must use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.zip | 
  perl -pe 's/.* ABCD (\w+) \d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} .*/$1/x'
```

Comment: using find has the recursive advantage, but using maxdepth 1 is the same as your `ls` version, except longer :)